# Showing all posts and custom post types by using one category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I included a category in my Menu. When I click  the category in my menu, nothing shows up of this categorie. I expected that at least one published post of a custom post type shows up.

My custom post type has the link:

```
mysite.com/customPostTypeName/PostTitle
```

My category site has the link:

```
mysite.com/category/testCategorie
```

I would like to show in the menu a link which displays all posts and custom post types of a certain category.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

My post type looks like the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_matratze' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts_matratze() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Matratzen', '' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Matratze', '' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Matratzen', '' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
                "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "matratze", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,

        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "trackbacks", "custom-fields", "comments", "revisions", "author", "page-attributes", "post-formats" ),      
        "taxonomies" => array( "category", "post_tag" ),
            );
    register_post_type( "matratze", $args );

// End of cptui_register_my_cpts_matratze()
}
```

I haven`t registered any Taxonomie.

Comment: Make sure that it is set to "public" so that it is publicly queryable, and that you activate has_archive (I'm not sure if the last one is required but it's worth a shot). Otherwise you will need to write a custom tax query for your category template, in which you include all the post types you want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing blank because there are no posts in it. The default category taxonomy is only connected with the default post type. To enable it to use it with a custom post type, add the following line to the register_post_type configuration

```
'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
```

For more info : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#taxonomies

Comment: I am using CPT UI plugin. Any suggestions how to manage it there? I appreciate your reply!

Comment: I have no idea about that plugin so it would be better to ask that to the support of that plugin.